# ResourceBundle локализация

Tags: java

Пишу небольшое консольное приложение с локализацией. Возникла распространенная проблема с выводом символов русского языка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Метод, определяющий локаль:

```
public ResourceBundle toBundle() {

    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("message", locale);

    return bundle;
}
```

вывод сообщения:

```
String st = toBundle().getString("day.time");

        String s1 = new String(st.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

        System.out.println(s1);
```

сам файл message_ru_RU.properties, находящийся в папке src/main/resources

```
 morning.time=утро
 day.time=день
 evening.time=вечер
 night.time=ночь
```

текст необходимо хранить именно в проперти - файле

Comment: Какая именно проблема возникла? И какую версию Java используете?

Comment: Java 8. 
Символы выводятся как знаки вопроса: "????"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle